# How to get real IP address from Digital Ocean Load Balancer -> Nginx -> Node script?

Tags: node.js, nginx, digital-ocean

Previously when I was using Nginx -> Node script only, I was able to get the visitor's real IP address using an Nginx config like this:

```
   location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
```

But now, everything is behind a Digital Ocean Load Balancer. As a result, the node script receives the Digital Ocean Load Balancer's IP address.

Have any of your experienced this before, and how did you solve it?

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this.

With Digital Ocean load balancers, if you use "passthrough" for the load balancer -> droplet setup, it won't pass the client IP.

You need to configure the load balancer (via the Digital Ocean UI) to use a "new certificate" (it can be any certificate).

So the DO load balancer setup will be HTTPS/443 -> new certificate -> HTTPS/443.

I believe this is called terminating the SSL connection at the load balancer.

Answer (score 2):

DigitialOcean Load Balancers set the X-Forwarded-For, X-Forwarded-Proto, and X-Forwarded-Port

In your case :

```
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_x_forwarded_for
```